# Gearman persistent queue not saved in Postgres

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, gearman

I have a problem with Gearman 0.32 (ppa:gearman-developers/ppa)- it doesn't save queue in Postgres for queue persistence.

- Gearman is running, I can add jobs (example with DEBUG verbosity on pastebin for better readability: http://pastebin.com/3uRds4yi )
- Postgres connection string is OK - I managed to login/access db using same data from same host
- Gearman connects to Postgres - if queue table doesn't exist in DB it creates it.

And despite all that NOTHING is added to DB. I have 0 workers registered and as I add new jobs to queue they get queued, but never saved in persistent storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

When using `Pecl Gearman` extension tasks added using `GearmanClient::addTask` (and high/low priority variants of the function) will be added to Gearman job queue, but not saved to database if PHP script times out before `GearmanClient::runTasks` returns result.

Use `GearmanClient::addTaskBackground` instead.